# Magento 2 How to duplicate category products into another category

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, magento2.3, category-products

I am working on **duplicate category**, In my controller file, I am able to duplicate the category but **I need to assign the same products to the newly created category from the old one.**

i.e.
I have the category name **"Abc"** has **10 products** and **2 of them are In-stock / out of stock / disable**, now I duplicate the category with and **the new name is "Xyz".** I want to assign all 10 products into "Xyz".

How could I achieve this functionality?

```
class DuplicateCategory extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
protected $_categoryFactory;    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

$parentCategoryObj = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load(2);
$duplicateCategoryObj = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load(8);
$catagoryObject = $this->_categoryFactory->create();

$categoryName = $duplicateCategoryObj->getName();
$categoryUrlKey = strtolower($this->getCategoryUrlKey($categoryName));

$catagoryObject->setPath($parentCategoryObj->getPath())
    ->setParentId($parentCategory)
    ->setName($duplicateCategoryObj->getName())
    ->setUrlKey($categoryUrlKey)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setIsActive(true);
$catagoryObject->save();
}
```

Comment: Can you please upload your code logic which you have done?

Comment: Use [this extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/copy-duplicate-categories-magento-2-extension.html) instead if you are OK with it. It will make your life easier with duplicating categories.

Answer (score 0):

When possible I would try to use APIs for interacting with the Magento core.

Consider using:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
```

The duplicate product assignment might look something like

```
$categoryProductLinks = $this->categoryLinkManagement
    ->getAssignedProducts($sourceCategory->getId());

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface $categoryProductLink */
foreach ($categoryProductLinks as $categoryProductLink) {
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($categoryProductLink->getSku());
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    array_push($categoryIds, $newCategory->getId());
    $this->categoryLinkManagement
         ->assignProductToCategories($product->getSku(), $categoryIds);
}
```

Note:

- Above is just an example of an idea and not tested code.
- While
  productRepository->get returns
  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface the underlying object
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product has getCategoryIds()